# Почему не запускает функцию?

Tags: php, html

```
<?php
 function dw($value){
   echo $value;
 }
?>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<button value="OK" onclick="<?PHP dw('Привет!'); ?>"></button>
</body>
</html>
```

вроде должно работать, что не так?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Может, так?

```
<button value="OK" onclick="alert('<?php dw('Привет!'); ?>')"></button>
```

Answer (score 0):

А вы проверьте исходный код HTML в браузере, что там у вас находится?

Скорее всего, все правильно, просто кнопка, у которой прописан onclick="Привет!" ничего не будет делать и не покажет. Так как в onclick записывается код на другом языке JavaScript, и он в данном случае не корректен, в отличие от кода PHP.

Проще проверить так:

```
<?php
 function dw($value){
   echo $value;
 }
?>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<?PHP dw('Привет!'); ?>
</body>
</html>
```